# Blank Blue Screen During Windows 8.1 Install?

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, windows-installation, windows-8.1

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Windows 8.1 on a home-built PC.  Specs are here: http://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/t823x/build_complete_hush_1450_silent_gamingphotography/

The video card has been swapped out for an MSI GTX 760, and the SSD is now a 256GB Mushkin Chronos Deluxe.

After the Windows logo appears for a bit, I get a blank dark-ish blue screen with a mouse cursor, but nothing else happens.

I've tried two images (RTM and now the release version from today) with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, RTM is what I meant.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be failing to boot... This is before any installation occurs, mind.  And I don't want to upgrade, I want to do a fresh install.

Comment: Wow... I am sorry.  20 questions about the upgrade will do that.  Try the video port on the motherboard.  I would also try safe mode a blank blue screen indicates a driver problem.  The GA release and the RTM build is actually the same thing

Comment: You can boot an install DVD in safe mode?  Keep in mind that the Windows 7 install I'm hoping to blow away boots fine.

Comment: Are you booting to the disk itself or running the setup from within windows?

Comment: The latter.  Updating the BIOS fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to switch to UEFI Boot from BIOS (also enable FastBoot option)... and partition your SSD as GPT

Comment: This didn't appear to correct the issue.  I'm going to update the BIOS and see if that helps.

Comment: Once I updated the BIOS, I was able to enable Secure Boot, which fixed this issue.